# Stack Trace not return lineNo and Filename

Tags: c#, stack-trace

i am cathing exceptions to writing but it's return null for fileName and return 0 for line number. i open any other project and it runs succesfully. i think it's related with debug settings how can i change my project setting to response my code ?

```
public static void WriteUnexpectedErrors(Exception ex)
{
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
    string fileName = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
    int lineNo = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
}
```

This code came some result  but at above code not working especially GetFrame(0).GetFileName();

```
foreach (var frame in trace.GetFrames())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(frame.GetFileName()))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(frame.GetFileName());
                    }
                    if (frame.GetFileLineNumber() > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(frame.GetFileLineNumber());
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Do you have the PDB file deployed with the EXE?

Comment: yes i have seen one in bin/debug file.

Comment: Check your value for `<system.web><compilation debug="true"/></system.web>`. If it's false, change it to true for your local environment

Comment: but i am using console app. How can i write for app.config

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Debug Info` in the Advanced Settings on the Build tab on your project properties.  Make sure the Debug Info settings is set to `full` or `pdb-only`.

[image]

Comment: did this but both `full` and `pdb-only` does not give filename and line number